# Implementing Comparable in java 1.4.2

Tags: java, class, comparable

I have a Java question.
I'm trying to implement Comparable in my class.  Based on my research, the statement for my class would be:

```
public class ProEItem implements Comparable<ProEItem> {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String material;
    private int bomQty;

// other fields, constructors, getters, & setters redacted

    public int compareTo(ProEItem other) {
        return this.getName().compareTo(other.getName());
        }
}// end class ProEItem
```

However, I get the compile error that { is expected after Comparable in the class declaration.  I believe this is because I'm stuck with java 1.4.2 (yes, it's sadly true).

So I tried this:

```
   public class ProEItem implements Comparable {
        private String name;
        private String description;
        private String material;
        private int bomQty;

    // other fields, constructors, getters, & setters redacted

        public int compareTo(ProEItem other) {
            return this.getName().compareTo(other.getName());
            }
    }// end class ProEItem
```

Without the ProEItem after comparable, but then my compile error is this:

```
"ProEItem is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(java.lang.Object) in java.lang.Comparable
public class ProEItem implements Comparable {"
```

So my question is what am I doing wrong to implement comparable in 1.4.2?
Thank you.

Comment: I would encourage your systems team to allow you to upgrade. Even Java 5 hasn't been supported for almost 2 years now. I know this doesn't help the immediate problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compareTo() method should take Object and then you should cast it to ProEItem inside the method.`

```
public int compareTo(Object other) {
        return this.getName().compareTo(((ProEItem)other).getName());
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be declared

```
public int compareTo(Object other)
```

You then have to down-cast the `other` object to your type, `ProEItem` and do the comparison. It is OK to do so without checking the type of `other`, as `compareTo` declares that it can throw `ClassCastException` (caller beware).

Answer (score 0):

`compareTo` takes `Object` as a parameter in 1.4.2

e.g.

```
public int compareTo(Object other) {
            return this.getName().compareTo(other.getName());
}
```